# Taylor series for e^x in probability theory.

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion

I'm working on some probability theory questions from old exams, where we have a given distribution X $\epsilon$ Po($\lambda$). I'm to show that $\psi(t) =E[e^{tX} | X > 0] =  \frac{e^-\lambda}{1-e^-\lambda}(e^{\lambda e^t} -1)$ (where $\psi(t)$ is the moment generating function).

Now I quite easily arrive at the conclusion that $E[e^{tX} | X > 0] = \frac{e^-\lambda}{1-e^-\lambda}\sum \frac{(e^t \lambda)^k}{k!}$ however this is where I don't know how to continue. According to the lecture notes we can use series expansion for $e^x$ to determine that the sum simplifies to $e^{\lambda e^t} - 1$. Granted my calculus is a bit rusty but I can't for the love of me figure out how that makes sense, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Blindly replace $x$ by $e^{t} \lambda$ in the series for $e^{x}$. Note that the first term in the series is $1$.

Comment: Thank you that clarified it!